# Can ECDSA certificates have RSA signature?

Tags: ssl, cryptography, certificate, ssl-certificate, digital-certificate

I need information related to ECDSA certificates. As far as I know ECDSA certificate should contain the ECDSA signature but I see that facebook and google server certificates have the ECDSA certificates with RSA signature.
Is it possible to have the ECDSA certificates with RSA signatures?

Comment: ECDSA and RSA are in no way compatible, so I find *"i see that facebook and google server certificates have the ECDSA certificates with RSA signature"*. Please show what you see. Besides, this is not a programming question and might be better suited for [security.se].

Comment: I captured the packets and i see that facebook chooses the cipher ECDHE_ECDSA which mean it want to get authenticated  by ECDSA certificate and will send the ECDSA cetificate, following is the o/p of packet capture...

Comment: Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         aa:91:ae:52:01:8c:60:f6:02:b6:94:eb:af:6e:eb:dd:3c:c8:
         e1:6f:17:ab:b8:28:80:ec:dc:54:82:56:24:c1:16:08:e1:c2:

Comment: same certificate can be seen on browser as well

Answer (score 6):

The signature for a certificate is created by the issuer using the key of the issuer. Thus if the certificate A has an ECC key inside (i.e. ECDSA certificate) but the issuer B has an RSA key then the signature for A will be an RSA signature, because this is what the issuer has for signing.

For example in the case of facebook.com the certificate itself has an ECC key, but the issuers certificate DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA has an RSA key. Because the signature for the facebook certificate is done by the issuer with the issuers key it must use RSA too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: my question here is, if certificate is signed by RSA keys then it will RSA based authentication of server by client not ECDSA... then cipher should be like ECDHE_RSA not ECDHE_ECDSA..

Comment: following is the excerpt from RFC-4492.. which expects signature in ECDSA when ECDHE_ECDSA is choosen...

Comment: ECDHE_ECDSA Certificate MUST contain an
ECDSA-capable public key. It
MUST be signed with ECDSA.

Comment: @rakeshsharma: for deeper information I recommend http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14207/does-a-ca-need-to-have-the-same-type-of-key-as-the-certificates-it-is-signing-r

Comment: @rakeshsharma I do know that the answer of Steffen *is correct*, but I'm not sure if it is *in the context of TLS 1.0 / RFC 4492* (which specifies the use of curves in TLS 1.0).

Comment: thanks a lot @Steffen this indeed helped me... and it explains that CA keys can sign any of certificates.. it does not matter what keys server certificates contains...

Comment: @steffen Cipher "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD ...
" uses ECDSA for Authentication ...   if server choosing the same cipher and sending the certificate signed by RSA then isn't it RSA authentication(client will use the CA's RSA public key to verify) ? this is the questing bothering me now and i see the same with google and facebook where used the same CIPHER and sent the certificate signed by RSA keys. you can check the server certificate technical details on browser for the cipher for google and facebook server

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes: Please check my latest comment and help me plz  in clarifying the doubt.  Thanks in advance

Comment: @rakeshsharma: you are confusing authentication with the servers certificate with the validation of the certificate. The authentication checks if the server owns the private key to the public key in the certificate. The validation checks if the certificate is signed directly or indirectly by a trusted party. The cipher only describes the authentication part.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich for your response, now it is making sense to me. if i understand correctly, In case of  ECDSA , authentication will happen via  serverkeyexchange  message where KEY will be signed by server private key and client will verify using the server certificate public key... because  ClientKeyExchange(in case of ECDHE_ECDSA) will send the key as it is.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: Appreciate your response

Answer (score 2):

Steffen's answer is correct for X.509 standard and many browsers
which are based on standard SSL libraries support the case. However, in this rough real world, I found some devices rejecting ECDSA certificate which has RSA signatures, with TLS 1.2 negotiation.

I think the reason is that the authors of the devices followed the RFC-4492, (** is mine)

```
2.2.  ECDHE_ECDSA
In ECDHE_ECDSA, the server's certificate **MUST** contain an ECDSA-
capable public key and **be signed with ECDSA.**

The server sends its ephemeral ECDH public key and a specification of
the corresponding curve in the ServerKeyExchange message.  These
parameters MUST be signed with ECDSA using the private key
corresponding to the public key in the server's Certificate.
```

though RFC-5246, TLS1.2, loosened this restriction. (** is mine):

```
7.4.4.  Certificate Request
...
If the client provided a "signature_algorithms" extension, then all
certificates provided by the server MUST be signed by a
hash/signature algorithm pair that appears in that extension. **Note
that this implies that a certificate containing a key for one
signature algorithm MAY be signed using a different signature
algorithm (for instance, an RSA key signed with a DSA key).  This is
a departure from TLS 1.1, which required that the algorithms be the
same.**  Note that this also implies that the DH_DSS, DH_RSA,
ECDH_ECDSA, and ECDH_RSA key exchange algorithms do not restrict the
algorithm used to sign the certificate.  Fixed DH certificates MAY be
signed with any hash/signature algorithm pair appearing in the
extension.  The names DH_DSS, DH_RSA, ECDH_ECDSA, and ECDH_RSA are
historical.
```

So be warned that such a device exists.